# Is it safe to "FLUSH STATUS" in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysqladmin

We have deployed REDIS to hold some frequent query result to reduce number of connections made on Database server. We need to find out Max_used_connection after deploying REDIS. So we plan to reset mysql status variable [Max_used_connection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Max_used_connections).

While googling i found to reset Max_used_connections we need to use FLUSH STATUS.

Is it safe to execute **Flush status** in production ?
MySQL docs says:

> **FLUSH STATUS** -  resets the counters for key caches (default and named) to zero and sets Max_used_connections to the current number of open connections.

I don't know impact of resetting counters for key caches.

Is it possible to reset [Max_used_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Max_used_connections) alone ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it safe to execute Flush status in production ?

- Well it should not affect anything as such but resets the status counters and you should be "Safe".

> Is it possible to reset Max_used_connections alone ?

- No

> but "We need to find out Max_used_connection after deploying ...."

- How about introducing graphs into monitoring? Say Cacti / Grafana will give you good glances over what's-going-on-inside-your-mysql!

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not safe to run `FLUSH STATUS` in MySQL.  If you run this command on a replica and you have GTIDs enabled, this creates an errant GTID on that replica because `FLUSH STATUS` ends-up in the binary log.  The safe way to run this command is `FLUSH LOCAL STATUS` or `FLUSH NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG STATUS`.

Running `FLUSH STATUS` on a primary is safe-ish, but it will also propagate to all replicas.